# Java how to get 1D array reference from a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, reference

Say I have a 2D array:

```
int[][] foo = new int[3][10];
```

I want to have a better alias name for each 1D array, like:

```
int[] xAxis = foo[0];
int[] yAxis = foo[1];
int[] zAxis = foo[2];
```

Is `xAxis` a reference to the 1st 1D array in 2D array? Cause I don't want the array to be copied again. If not, how do I get the reference to 1D arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson22.htm

> ...with one-dimensional arrays, when passing an multi-dimensional
>   array as argument, the array is treated as a reference. This makes it
>   possible for the method to modify the array and return it changed

when you declare this

```
new int[3][10]
```

you got one object array with 3 values: array1, array2, array3. All arrays will share the same defined size (10)

so, yes! in this case, `foo[0] -> array1[10]` , `foo[1] -> array2[10]` and `foo[2] -> array3[10]`

consider this one: what did you expect if `foo[0]` didn't pointing to another array? how `(foo[x])[y]` should works?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is reference to 1st Array in 2nd Array. You can verify it by yourself by modifing the xAxis array and check if reflects in 1st 1D array of 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes. The statement `int[] xAxis = foo[0];` assigns the 1D array in `foo[0]` to the variable `xAxis`. Since arrays in Java are objects, this just assigns a reference. The data isn't being copied again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, array's are not primitive types, instead they are reference types.

So in your case `xAxis` will be a reference to `foo[0]`. Which means changes will be visible in both `foo[0]` and `xAxis`.

But you need to change your first statement to,

```
int[][] foo = new int[3][10];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out this code.

```
    int[][] foo = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };

    int[] xAxis = foo[0];
    int[] yAxis = foo[1];
    int[] zAxis = foo[2];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            foo[i][j]++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        System.out.println("X: " + xAxis[i] + " Y: " + yAxis[i] + " Z: " + zAxis[i]);
    }
```

And yes, it indeed does reference it.